# Android: ADB update Google Play Services 'Failure'

Tags: android, adb

Trying to follow [this Google+ Login tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/).

---

Start application and I get this error

> You need to update Google Play Services to use this application

- Pressing `Update` does not do anything.
- Ignoring this dialog and pressing `Login` crashes the application.

---

Using the terminal in Windows 8 to update the Play Services on my emulator,

> adb install com.android.vending-20140218.apk ........ 
>   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION perm=com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION pkg=com.google.android.gms]

> adb install com.google.android.gms-20140218.apk .......
>   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION perm=com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE pkg=com.android.vending]

---

I tried uninstalling both using `adb uninstall` and `adb install -r` but it just responds with

> Failure

---

**Emulator**

- Nexus 5 with Android 5.0
- targetSdk Android 5.0
- minSdk Android 5.0
- Buildtools
  19.1.0.

Comment: I get the same thing. These error messages are sooooo helpful. Any luck solving this?

Comment: Yes the thing i did to solve it was to ignore it. I stopped using an emulator to get it to work :( But feel free to tell me if you get a solid solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue:
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION ...

un-installing the app from the device and re-installing the app solved it.

Comment: What did you uninstall? The Google Play Services application or your application?

Comment: my application. and then re-installed it. try updating the Google Play Services through the android SDK manager as well.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when you change the Android version off your device.

Try to uninstall the application directly in the device and re-install it.

Normaly the problem are solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved in this thread:
[INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION... C2D_MESSAGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043933/install-failed-duplicate-permission-c2d-message)

The error is actually due to a duplicate app with the same permission but a different signature.
I blogged about a work around [here](http://lethargicpanda.tumblr.com/post/103432366121/use-gradle-manifest-merger-to-workaround).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same on Nexus 7 with Android 5.0.
Please make sure "Unknown sources" is enabled. I.e. you can install apps from sources other than Google Play.