# Error -505 INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION:

Tags: android

I am working on a android VOIP Dialer. I unable to install my current app along with old app in a device.

> 01-07 12:05:05.115: E/Finsky(28214): [1] PackageInstallerImpl$2.onReceive: Error -505 while installing com.current.app: INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package com.current.app attempting to redeclare permission android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP already owned by com.old.app

the permission in manifest.

```
<permission
    android:name="android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.COST_MONEY"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

I have tried protectionLevel both signature and dangerous.

How can I solve this issue.

Comment: check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/27161589/1320616

Comment: are you testing on lollipop or latest?

Comment: I have tested in lollipop(5.0 and 5.1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you are trying to declare same permission in two applications.

In order to keep both application installed, common solution for this problem is to use a dynamic prefix for your permission, preventing conflicts with other apps (as it happens for GCM configuration too):

```
<permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP"
    android:permissionGroup="${applicationId}.permission-group.COST_MONEY"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Be careful to have `applicationId` value assigned in your Gradle configuration under `android > defaultConfig`.

Comment: got the same problem in cordova but I think it is not a solution in my case.