# Fail when i'm trying to install the application

Tags: android, gradle

I've changed the package name, and right now I have some troubles trying to install the application on my tablet.

Error:Execution failed for task ':MobileUI:installDebug'.

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package com.name2 attempting to redeclare permission com.name2.permission.REPORTING already owned by com.mobile.name1

I've uninstalled the application from the tablet and also factory reset.
Also, clean project, rebuild, clean gradle .. etc

Even with this error the application is installed on the tablet, but it doesn't work properly .

On the Virtual Emulator everything is fine.

How can I solve this ? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error -505 INSTALL\_FAILED\_DUPLICATE\_PERMISSION:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649079/error-505-install-failed-duplicate-permission)

Comment: Check this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043933/install-failed-duplicate-permission-c2d-message