# Google Push Notification c2dm from Android 2.3 to 5.x INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION perm=com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE

Tags: android, notifications, push, android-c2dm

I got a strange problem:
to make push possible also on 2.3 devices (even app-installable) you need to declare:

```
<permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
```

and on higher api levels you have to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
```

works perfect for all api levels except 21 (5.x),

if you have a manifest like above you get the following problem on installation:

```
INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION perm=com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE pkg=com.google.android.gsf
```

Google nearly says nothing, possibly many people just dropping api level 10,
but we have to still make it possible.
So any solution already known?

cheers && thx

Comment: Checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043933/install-failed-duplicate-permission-c2d-message

Comment: I also have this same issue...