# SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent REGISTER without permission on Android 5

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, android-5.0-lollipop, securityexception

after updating my device to Android 5, I get the following exception when starting my app:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
```

My manifest should look correct:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="custom.package"
android:versionCode="7"
android:versionName="1.5.0">

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission android:name="custom.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="custom.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register with GCM and receive message -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" />

<application
    ...

    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="custom.package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
```

What am I missing? On Android <= 4 everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you put `<service>` tag in your Manifest?

Try to compare following `AndroidManifest.xml` to see where went wrong:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="custom.package"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.5.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="app.cloudstringers.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
        android:name="app.cloudstringers.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="app.cloudstringers.Cloudstringers"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="ui.fragment.RegisterWithAccountsFragment" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- Receiver GCM -->
    <receiver
        android:name="app.cloudstringers.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="app.cloudstringers" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Service GCM -->
    <service
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="app.cloudstringers.GcmIntentService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="app.cloudstringers.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />` Shouldn't `app.cloudstringers` actually be `custom.package` which is the app's package name?

Comment: Or better yet, [`${applicationId}`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35629480/1276636) to make it less problematic in future (in case one wants to use product flavours).

Answer (score 0):

The design was changed from Lollipop.

Please refer to the [change](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#custom_permissions).

> Android 5.0 includes a behavior change to ensure that only one app can define a given custom permission, unless signed with the same key as other apps defining the permission.