# Installing Google Play Games on an Emulator

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to install Google Play Games on an emulator.

I downloaded the latest Google Play Games APK from apkmirror.

I've got a Nexus 5 API 23 emulator.

However, when I try to install it on the emulator I get an error message:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION perm=com.google.android.gms.permission.GAMES_DEBUG_SETTINGS pkg=com.google.android.gms]
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing it?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, tried uninstalling what? There is no Google Play Games on the emulator, because the installation fails (there's just Google Play Services on default)

Comment: Would it be possible (read: relatively simple) to modify the AndroidManifest.xml inside the Google Play Games APK, to possibly remove this permission or something? I have very little experience with APKs, and the AndroidManifest.xml does not seem to be in plain text...

Comment: As I gathered, this is a security feature added in Android 5.0... failing everything else, I guess I could download the 4.4 KitKat images and this "error" would not appear?

Comment: I've found a [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043933/install-failed-duplicate-permission-c2d-message) that might help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think any of the answers actually help in my case. If I've understood the problem correctly, it's Google Play Services (?) & Google Play Games that have duplicate permissions. I cannot uninstall either, and I cannot modify their manifests.

Comment: I've browsed upon the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#custom_permissions) for Android 5.0 and it seems that it will only accept custom permissions associated with the same key. However, you can still install it with lower Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading the Android 4.4 (Kitkat) image, and the Google Play Games app installed correctly. However, it doesn't work 100% because the GPG depends of the Google Play Store (which I have not installed). But this is fine for my needs (the game works).