# applicationId manifest placeholder for multiple build flavors not working

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, buildconfig, manifest-merging

I am modifying current android project so it can be installed on same device for multiple flavors and build configs.

**build.gradle:**

```
{
    // ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
            manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
            onesignal_app_id: "xxxx",
            onesignal_google_project_number: "xxxx"
        ]
    // ...
    }

    productFlavors {
        production {
            applicationId "com.myapp"
            // ...
        }

        dev {
            applicationId "com.myapp.dev"
            // ...
        }

        // ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // ...
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            // ...
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />      
    <!-- ... -->

    <receiver
        android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- ... -->
</manifest>
```

When I compile both debug and release version of the same flavor, I got error message:

...

INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION

perm=com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE

pkg=com.myapp.dev

...

manifestApplicationId placeholder came from AndroidManifest.xml on OneSignal library as instructed on https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup

Anybody have a clue how to fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043933/install-failed-duplicate-permission-c2d-message. You need to uninstall the app from the device and reinstall it.

Comment: @Blehi: Of course uninstalling the installed variant will get rid of the error. But my goal is to install all variants to the same device. Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

OneSignal requires the `manifestPlaceholders` key `manifestApplicationId` to be set to your `applicationId` (AKA your package name).

This can be done by setting it in your `buildTypes` like the following.

```
buildTypes {
   debug {
      defaultConfig {
         manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                 onesignal_app_id               : "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
                                 onesignal_google_project_number: "111111111"]
       }
   }

   release {
      defaultConfig {
         manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                 onesignal_app_id               : "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222",
                                 onesignal_google_project_number: "222222222"]
      }
   }
}
```

**Update 1**: OneSignal-Android 3.3.0 no longer requires `manifestApplicationId`.

**Update 2**: OneSignal-Android 4.0.0 no longer requires any `manifestPlaceholders` values. [Instead `OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID)` needs to be called at runtime](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added these placeholders inside defaultConfig closure on every buildType like above code, now I got build failed: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processProductionReleaseManifest'.
> No record for key [permission#${manifestApplicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE]

Comment: Edit: I forgot to remove tools:overrideLibrary and tools:override on my manifest which I added before. After I did that, the error is back to "duplicate permission". Still trying to find the solution by now...

Comment: @Wellsen After you make this `.gradle` change you will need to uninstall both apps then reinstall them. One of them most likely has the wrong permission so this is needed.

Comment: Are the nested `defaultConfig` blocks intentional here?

Comment: without `defaultConfig` nesting. gradlew fails to build on mine

Comment: Do we need to create two different projects in google console for debug and production?

Comment: @RamMandal No, you can use the same FCM SenderID / Project number for any many package names as you want.

Comment: How can we use it for different flavours build type?

Comment: Can we create two different Onesignal project with same server api key and project no. For live and production?

Comment: I use version `3.6` with productFlavors, it still need to set `manifestApplicationId`.