# INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION when try to install the app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, installation, android-emulator

Ive wrote an app. Everthing was fine but then i wanted to work on it on my computer at home. The problem is that i receive the error message "INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION" when i want to start the app in the emulator. At work I use the same settings for the emulator. And there werent problems with other apps when i tried to work on it on 2 different computers.

Sorry if I havent gave u enough informations, but i am new in programming.

Maybe somebody have made similar experiences and could help me with it.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043933/install-failed-duplicate-permission-c2d-message

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `${applicationId}` on the place of packageName in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Replace

```
<permission
android:name="com.example.testapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.testapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

to

```
<permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
 
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

And in receiver’s `intent-filter`:
replace

```
<category android:name="com.example.testapp"/>
```

to

```
<category android:name="${applicationId}"/>
```

And DUPLICATE_PERMISSION issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Check `AndroidManifest.xml` for duplicate permissions.

Have look at this :
https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-onesignal/issues/352