# install failed due to duplicate permission

Tags: android

I'm trying to install the app on my Samsung M31s phone, but every time I'm getting the following error -

```
Error: INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package com.glance.tv.internal attempting to redeclare permission glance.sdk.api.status.permission.READ already owned by com.samsung.android.dynamiclock'
```

Is there any way to bypass this permission?
I tried removing it from the manifesto, but it is still not working.

```
 <permission
    android:name="com.glance.PERMISSION_READ"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />
```

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043933/install-failed-duplicate-permission-c2d-message

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane No, I'm facing this issue on a Samsung device. I cannot remove all the read permissions from manifesto.

Comment: The `<permission>` element in your question has an `android:name` that does not match the problematic permission name from the error.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for pointing this out; it helped me to resolve the issue.